# Error in ReduxToolkit can't handle API error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a API for weather app I am trying to connect it's correctly but I was test it by enter wrong values in input field I get error but can't resolve this error when enter wrong data

Error like this:

in `Dashboard.js:55`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

and

`Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.`

you can check all code from [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-browser-qiqtm7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

extra reducer

```
export const getDataReducer = createAsyncThunk('weatherData/getData', async (args, thunkAPI) => {
    const { rejectWithValue } = thunkAPI;
    try {
        const data = await axios.get(`https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=${api_key}&q=${args.country}&format=json&num_of_days=5`, {
    headers: {...}
  })
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(e => console.log("fetchError",e))
        console.log('new new new',data)
        return data
    } catch (error) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.message)
    }
})
```

Slice

```
[getDataReducer.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        },
        [getDataReducer.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.error = false
            state.getData = action?.payload?.data
        },
        [getDataReducer.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.error = true
            state.getData = action?.payload?.data
        },
```

redux call

```
const [country, setCountry] = useState(undefined)
const {getData: APIData ,isLoading} = useSelector(state => state.getDataSlice)
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getDataReducer({country}))
    },[dispatch, country])
```

any help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred due to **request** is undefined

```
<WeatherInfo
          isLoading={isLoading}
          city={APIData && APIData.request ? APIData.request[0]?.query?.split(',')[0] : ''}
          country={APIData && APIData.request ? APIData.request[0]?.query?.split(',')[1] : ''}
          latitude={latitude}
          longitude={longitude}
        />
        <Temp
          isLoading={isLoading}
          celsius={APIData && APIData.current_condition ? APIData.current_condition[0]?.temp_C : ''}
          fahrenheit={APIData && APIData.current_condition ? APIData.current_condition[0]?.temp_F : ''}
          weatherStatus={APIData && APIData.current_condition && APIData.current_condition[0].weatherDesc ? APIData.current_condition[0].weatherDesc?.value : ''}
          ForC={ForC}
          setForC={setForC}
        />
```

This is how I changed the code, but you can repost it to cleaner code.

I changed also in the *codesandbox*.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-browser-qiqtm7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

best.

Comment: Thank you very much, my brother, and your effort. You are great. I want to warn you that the link you added is the same as mine. You can correct it.
And thank you very much with all my heart